# Test scenarios for preview feature functionality

Tags: manual, manual-testing

I would want few test scenarios for a preview feature that is where the view page can be only readonly and only the latest result should be dispayed

Answer (score 0):

Listing few of them below:

1. Verify whether all the fields filled are populated and are being displayed on preview screen.
2. If you are using any form of WYSIWYG editor, then make sure the applied font formats like bold, italic are visible on preview screen.
3. If there is any sort of media field in use like an image or a video, verify whether the media is also being displayed on preview screen.
4. Verify the indentation of text and other kind of elements on preview screen .
5. Verify whether the links are displayed as hyper-links on preview screen.
6. Verify other types of features that are being used. For e.g. Is a tabular format displayed correctly? Are the quotes displayed correctly. In short all,sorts of formatting options available.
7. Always, verify the new changes are displayed on preview screen.
   Hope this helps you in designing more such scenarios.
8. For any kind of input fields like text field,text area, check-boxes, radio buttons etc. Verify that they are read-only and user cannot modify them on preview screen.